# How i can get Random element on code in JAVA?

Tags: java, selenium, random

I would like to get a random element on my code. For example i have 4 elements on my code in JAVA. I trying to get second element and start run program on this place. Another time when I start my program would be a one element. How do i get this?

```
        first element :

    while ( true ) {

         driver.get( "example_of_page" );
            WebElement formEmail = driver.findElement(By.name("email"));
            formEmail.sendKeys(Email1);
            WebElement formPassword = driver.findElement(By.name("pass"));
        formPassword.sendKeys(Password2);
        WebElement formRemember = driver.findElement(By.name("persistent"));
        formRemember.sendKeys(" ");
        formPassword.submit();

        second element :


        driver.get("example_of_page");
        WebElement formEmail = driver.findElement(By.name("email"));
        formEmail.sendKeys(Email2);
        WebElement formPassword = driver.findElement(By.name("password"));
        formPassword.sendKeys(Password2);
        WebElement formRemember = driver.findElement(By.name("remember"));
        formRemember.sendKeys(" ");
        WebElement formSubmit = driver.findElement(By.name("login_button"));
        formSubmit.click();

    the third element :

     driver.get("example_of_page");
        WebElement formEmail = driver.findElement(By.name("email"));
        formEmail.sendKeys(Email3);
        WebElement formPassword = driver.findElement(By.name("password"));
        formPassword.sendKeys(Password3);
        WebElement formRemember = driver.findElement(By.name("remember"));
        formRemember.sendKeys(" ");
        WebElement formSubmit = driver.findElement(By.name("login_button"));
        formSubmit.click();

    the fourth  element :

      driver.get( "example_of_page" );
            WebElement formEmail = driver.findElement(By.name("email"));
            formEmail.sendKeys(Email4);
            WebElement formPassword = driver.findElement(By.name("pass"));
        formPassword.sendKeys(Password4);
        WebElement formRemember = driver.findElement(By.name("persistent"));
        formRemember.sendKeys(" ");
        formPassword.submit();

}
```

How i can named, define this element in loop to run random element and start code from this place ? I use loop on this function, element and this element must not repeated on one loop.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get a random element in code in JAVA?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32162989/how-to-get-a-random-element-in-code-in-java)

Comment: Is this all done on the same form on the same page? In 2 cases you have name = "pass" and the other 2 are name = "password"... are they really different elements? Why are you using `.submit()` on a password field? Are you using `.sendKeys(" ")` to click a checkbox?

Comment: Whatever method/answer you choose... make sure that you write something to the log the indicates what login method you used so that you can reference it later if something fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the possible approach is: Use a switch-case block inside your while loop, with a random number generator. Switch should be performed on a local variable, and this variable must be assigned a random value in the beginning of each iteration of your while loop. The random number should be between 0 and n-1, where n is the number of elements.

Something like this :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //nubmer elements
    int n = 10;

    while(true){
           int switchToElement = getRandomNumber(n);
           switch(switchToElement) {
           case 0:
               //perform logic related to first element
               break;
           case 1:
               //perform logic related to second element
               break;
            // other cases..

            default:
                //should never reach this line unless there is a problem in your getRandomNumber
           }
        }
}

private static int getRandomNumber(int n) {
    // write logic to generate random number between 0 and n 

}
```

Comment: How i can use switch case block? I don't know how connect together.

Comment: Added a sample code snippet to give you an idea on how to use switch case block in this scenerio.

Comment: n in this case should be 3. Read [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/363692/2386774) to get some code for random number generation in a range.

Comment: Thank you this is very useful ;) but how i can do to not repeats the same element on one time loop ? I must make unique for each loop on element.

Comment: Not sure If I understood your question correctly, but the 'break' statement will enable you to execute the code only for one element per iteration. Is that what you were asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Random function to get a Random value have a look

**http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=62**

Comment: That really only answers a tiny fraction of Samantha's question.  Did you read it?